Why is the angular velocity differentiated as a constant?
Kinematics, uniform motion around a circle.
The angular velocity, which is defined as $\omega=\frac{\varphi}{t}$, when a point is rotated by an angle of $2\pi$ for a time equal to the rotation period, becomes $\omega=\frac{2\pi}{T}$, which allows us to obtain a formula for the relationship of linear and angular velocities $v=\omega r$. When formulating the law of motion, it allows you to rewrite $x=r\cos\varphi$ and $y=r\sin\varphi$ as $x=r\cos\omega t$ and $y=r\sin\omega t$. Next, to find the projections of the velocity vector, we differentiate the last two functions and get $v_x=-\omega r\sin\omega t$ and $v_y=\omega r\cos\omega t$.
Here I have a question: why do we differentiate $\omega$ as a constant? It seemed to me that this was a variable and it should have turned out something like $-rt\sin\omega t-r\omega\sin\omega t$. That is, $(\omega t)'=\omega +t$. However, to get the correct derivative, you need to differentiate this function as $(\omega t)'=\omega't+\omega t'=0+\omega t^{0}=0+\omega=\omega$, that is, $\omega=const$. The reason why we believe that $r=const$ I understand: the radius vector is always the same for a given circle, but the angular velocity, it seems to me, cannot be a constant, since it depends on time. What do I understand wrong?

For a uniformly circular motion, the angular velocity is constant by definition. Also: How did you arrive at the derivative $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} (\omega t) = \omega + t$? That does not make sense. It should be $\omega + \dot \omega t$.

You said $\omega = 2\pi/T$. Do you think $T$ is a function of $t$? How? That would be the only way $\omega$ could vary with $t$.

There is no requirement for the angular velocity $\omega$ to be constant in a pure circular motion. Indeed, if you parameterize the motion as $\vec{r} = \langle x, y \rangle = R \langle \cos \varphi, \sin \varphi \rangle$, then differentiating with respect to time, you obtain $\vec{v} = \langle v_x, v_y \rangle = \frac{d \vec{r}}{d t} = R \frac{d \varphi}{d t} \langle -\sin \varphi, \cos \varphi \rangle$.* The angular rate is defined as $\omega = \frac{d \varphi}{d t}$, so we have $v_x = -R \omega \sin \varphi$ and $v_y = R \omega \cos \varphi$. Again, this holds true even if $\omega$ is not constant in time. When people say "uniform" circular motion, they are usually referring to a motion for which $\omega = \Omega$ is constant in time.
* Note that this is for circular motion, for which $R$ is a constant. If $R$ is not constant, then you have $\vec{v} = \frac{d R}{d t} \langle \cos \varphi, \sin \varphi \rangle + R \frac{d \omega}{d t} \langle -\sin \varphi, \cos \varphi \rangle$; the extra term in front corresponds to the "radial" component of velocity, which is $\vec{0}$ in a purely circular motion.

By definition of uniform motion $\omega$ ( positive for angular velocity counter-clockwise ) is a constant, else there will be radial and circumferential components when time differentiated. The sign of velocity follows the sign of coordinate axes.
The velocity components can be any sign, $\pm$ depending on the quadrant.
However it is a matter of choice or convention or even habit referring to the first quadrant among the four quadrants for a start.. so when resolved the blue x- component of velocity is negative, red y - component is positive in the following diagram when linear velocity vector runs anticlockwise with respect the the pole or origin.

